# Get Hapi to Register @Hapi/Good Plugin Only Once

Tags: node.js, hapi, hapi-good

Hapi (v17 & 18) states that I can specify an option on `server.register` to make the plugin on get initialized once, regardless of however many times `server.register` is called with that plugin - [link to docs](https://hapijs.com/api#-await-serverregisterplugins-options). However, I have been unable to get this to work.

I have tried putting options an element on the object that gets passed into `server.register`. When I try to run the server, I get the error `[1] "once" conflict with forbidden peer "options"`. This leads me to believe that it must go in the `options` object.

```
await server.register({
    plugin: require('@hapi/good'),
    options: { /* omitted */ },
    once: true
  });
```

I try to add it to the options object that gets passed into `server.register`. However, I get this error `[1] "once" is not allowed`.

```
await server.register({
    plugin: require('@hapi/good'),
    options: {
      once: true,
      /* omitted */
    },
  });
```

I have not been able to find an example of this option anywhere online besides this [github issue](https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/611). However, that only covers the `routes`.

Comment: Related solution for performing unit testing with Hapi without Glue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57096151/1913185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@hapi/good` uses Joi to check what valid options can be passed in to the plugin. Check be read [here](https://github.com/hapijs/good/blob/master/lib/index.js#L29) in the source code. It seems that `@hapi/good` prohibits the use of `routes` and `once` because it denies all except the allowed entities by default. This seems to be an issue though because `once` is a configuration of the plugin for the server - not for the plugin.